# User appears twice in a WP_User_Query

Tags: wp-user-query

For some reason during a user query with a meta filter I have a user who when I `print_r` the results appears twice in the list...

I have checked the database, just in case there seemed to be duplicate entries but there is only a single value for the user. Also without the meta query the user only appears once.

Code:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( 
    array(
        'role'       => 'member',
        'orderby'    => 'registered',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(
             array(
                 'key'   => 'onTrial',
                 'value' => '1',
             ),
        ),
    )
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($user_query->results);
echo '</pre>';
```

Outputs (along with many others):

```
[54] => WP_User Object
    (
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 10410
                [user_login] => XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.co.uk
                [user_pass] => $P$XXXXXXX
                [user_nicename] => XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX
                [user_email] => XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.co.uk
                [user_url] => 
                [user_registered] => 2016-02-15 10:52:57
                [user_activation_key] => 
                [user_status] => 0
                [display_name] => XXXXXXX XXXXXXX
            )

        [ID] => 10410
        [caps] => Array
            (
                [member] => 1
            )

        [cap_key] => wp_capabilities
        [roles] => Array
            (
                [0] => member
            )

        [allcaps] => Array
            (
                [read] => 
                [no_admin_bar] => 1
                [member] => 1
            )

        [filter] => 
    )

[55] => WP_User Object
    (
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 10410
                [user_login] => XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.co.uk
                [user_pass] => $P$XXXXXXX
                [user_nicename] => XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX
                [user_email] => XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.co.uk
                [user_url] => 
                [user_registered] => 2016-02-15 10:52:57
                [user_activation_key] => 
                [user_status] => 0
                [display_name] => XXXXXXX XXXXXXX
            )

        [ID] => 10410
        [caps] => Array
            (
                [member] => 1
            )

        [cap_key] => wp_capabilities
        [roles] => Array
            (
                [0] => member
            )

        [allcaps] => Array
            (
                [read] => 
                [no_admin_bar] => 1
                [member] => 1
            )

        [filter] => 
    )
```

Now I can't show you the details obviously but note the ID and reg time outputted also the array numbers they appear in, `[54]` and `[55]`

No one else appears twice.

Thanks in advance - any input appreciated, small or large.

Comment: Does the meta_key/value pair exist twice for the same user in the usermeta table by chance?

Comment: That could explain it, since the generated query is joining the user meta table with the users table, without any distinct or group by.

Comment: Right - yes. Great shout. It appears twice against that user with different `umeta_id`s despite that particular bit of code using `update_user_meta` as an insert command. I didn't spot it before as to check I was using `foreach(` [get_user_meta($profileuser->ID)] `as $key => $value) {` How will that have happened?

Comment: hmm... typically that would happen if you are using add_user_meta and didn't specify unique. I need to give it some more thought.

Comment: I can obviously delete the entry from the database. However I'd like to know how that crept in there in the first place. That particular entry is made by a daily `wp_cron`. If it's adding multiple values on the user meta then that query sort of breaks down as useless and relies me spotting duplicates manually or using `array_unique` for everything... Which is annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for kicks...

#### Solution 1

**Note: Does not work with WP_User_Query (?)**

```
add_filter('posts_distinct', 'user_meta_query_distinct');

//your query here...

remove_filter('posts_distinct', 'user_meta_query_distinct');

function user_meta_query_distinct() { 
    return "DISTINCT"; 
}
```

#### Solution 2

Can you try adding `'relation' => 'OR'` to your meta_query:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( 
    array(
        'role'       => 'member',
        'orderby'    => 'registered',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(
             'relation' => 'OR', //should result in a DISTINCT query
             array(
                 'key'   => 'onTrial',
                 'value' => '1',
             ),
        ),
    )
);
```

See this diff:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/17582/17582.4.diff

```
if ( 'OR' == $meta_query->relation ) { 
    $this->query_fields = 'DISTINCT ' . $this->query_fields; 
}
```

Tracked down courtesy of this [trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17582).

See if that works...

Comment: I think the `posts_distinct` only works on `WP_Query`

Comment: Yup - the troublesome entry is still there.

Comment: @birgire interesting thanks, wasn't quite sure... There's a trac ticket that has rumblings of the same problem: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17582 with a solution albeit not entirely desirable if you read the OP.

Comment: @userabuser Sometimes I wish there would be concistancy among the query classes regarding the sql filters.. It looks like the trac ticket was closed due to inactivity  but I'm not sure it should have the "fixed" status ;-) The `DISTINCT` is added if there's an `OR` in the meta query aka  `$this->meta_query->has_or_relation()`.

Comment: @birgire totally agree... Regarding the trac ticket though, I thought it was closed out as a "wontfix" but then later saw it said "fixed" - if you have a look in `WP_User_Query` it appears that at least somewhere along the line similar code for a relation check === to OR was added that then adds DISTINCT to the SELECT. I wonder... that should still work though right?

Comment: yes and later on it was adjusted to a `$this->meta_query->has_or_relation()` check. We could just call this OR feature an *Easter Egg* in WordPress;-)

Comment: Brilliant and simple solution. The `'relation' => 'OR'` works a charm - thanks for your help. Thought I was going mad on that one.

Comment: No problem... this was a good question; shows you some of the gotchas and inconsistencies as birgie mentioned with `WP_User_Query` and `WP_Query` despite that both use `WP_Meta_Query`. Good luck on finding out where your duplicate meta_key entry is coming from...

Comment: This is still an issue 4 years later if one of your meta_query conditions matches a field for a user who has multiple rows with that meta key. For example if a user has two "program" keys that both match "> 0" they will return twice. The OR trick still works but I do not understand why DISTINCT isn't just in there by default. Such a wacky workaround!

Comment: @RadleySustaire welcome to WordPress and if you've been developing on WP for a long time then, welcome to WordPress . I'd be interested to know if there is a trac ticket lurk... wait a minute, deja-vu → https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17582 (having a giggle) but birgire said it best above "We could just call this OR feature an Easter Egg in WordPress;-)"

Comment: @Adam Speaking of deja vu... I'm back! Trying to fix the same problem on a different site. And stumbled upon this answer I already posted to! LOL. For next time here's a simple function + filter to drop in on a site which should fix the problem: https://gist.github.com/RadGH/877ee20d99eee73fb0e933f199d4b8fb

Comment: Thanks @RadleySustaire :)